# A word to mean "mark with one's name"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've had this on the tip of my brain for days and can't seem to come up with it. Is there a word meaning "to mark with one's name" or "to mark with a name"?

I feel like there must be something approximating this meaning with some Latin or Greek root.

"The recruit `marked his name` on the issued uniform with indelible ink."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be looking for the word **autograph**, which traces its etymology through *both* Latin and Greek:

> 1   to write one's name on or in; sign: to autograph a book.
>
> Origin of autograph.
> 1630–40; < Latin autographum, noun use of neuter of Latin autographus written with one's own hand < Greek autógraphos

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/autograph

It’s usually used humorously when the signer is not a celebrity.

Comment: This is good, I should have thought of it. It's not fair.

Comment: This was downvoted? Why? The word is perfect, the etymology is perfect too, to write (graphein) oneself (auto).

Comment: Or on the same lines - sign. The recruit signed his uniform, though perhaps in that situation 'autographed' is better.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I asked for and I can't believe I didn't come up with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the context of your sentence, I'd suggest:

## Inscribe (verb)

> Write or carve (words or symbols) on something, especially as a formal or permanent record.
>
> > "his name was **inscribed** on the new silver trophy."

*Inscribe* is from Latin *inscribere*.

Your sentence,

> The recruit ***inscribed*** his name on the issued uniform with indelible ink."

An excerpt from the book: [Musical Gumbo: The Music of New Orleans](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ed2TF84G-t8C&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22inscribe%22+%2B+%22indelible+ink%22&source=bl&ots=yp2SyvnssG&sig=pDgZR9dRALapwiMYC8Kf59qt_cc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1uKqs5e7cAhWKfysKHRS3A9YQ6AEwC3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22inscribe%22%20%2B%20%22indelible%20ink%22&f=false) By Grace Lichtenstein, Laura Dankner

> "Afterward, Jackson would sell T-shirts to fans and Thomas, a star without any pretensions whatsoever, would ***inscribe*** each one personally in indelible ink."

Comment: This would be fine if the OP didn't seem to need a word for "marked his name". With inscribe you will have to specify whose name is being inscribed.

Comment: @Zebrafish It's a nice suggestion with matching excerpt from the book. Thank!

Comment: This is super close, but "autograph" turns out to be exactly what I was looking for. I'm amused that my example sentence which I came up with on the spot has such a similar parallel, tool.